# Can I use assignment operator `:=` on a local variable in a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql

From my understanding the only difference between user variables `@var` and local variables like `var` is the latter are scoped between the `BEGIN` and `END` statements of a procedure whereas user variables exist for use in the connection as long as the connection remains open. So I would like to use local variables since I don't care if the variables exist after the procedure is done. Actually I would prefer they didn't exist outside of the procedure.

I am trying to use the following query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_test_table;
CREATE TABLE my_test_table(var INT DEFAULT 0);
INSERT INTO my_test_table VALUES (3);

DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_sp_test_function;
CREATE PROCEDURE my_sp_test_function() 
BEGIN
    DECLARE localVar INT DEFAULT 1;
    #SET @userVar = 1; ### If we swap this line for the one above the query works. ###

    SELECT
        localVar := t.var + 1 AS return_var
        #@userVar := t.var + 1 AS return_var
    FROM my_test_table AS t; 
END; //
DELIMITER ;

CALL my_sp_test_function();
```

but getting a syntax error near ":= t.var + 1". If we change the `DECLARE localVar` line to `SET @userVar` this exact query works. So is there a syntax fix I can make or a different technique I can use to save off a variable from a select statement while using local variables?

Comment: In the long run, `:=` is being deprecated and subject to removal from the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session variables are go

> ```
> CREATE TABLE my_test_table(var INT DEFAULT 0);
> INSERT INTO my_test_table VALUES (3);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE my_sp_test_function() 
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE localVar INT DEFAULT 1;
>     #SET @userVar = 1; ### If we swap this line for the one above the query works. ###
>
>     SELECT
>         t.var + 1 AS return_var INTO  localVar
>         #@userVar := t.var + 1 AS return_var
>     FROM my_test_table AS t;
>     SELECT localVar;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL my_sp_test_function();
> ```
>
> ```
> | localVar |
> | -------: |
> |        4 |
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4bca4301977cfbadfd71174cec7d5687)*

But Variables act different ly from @ sessionvaroables which you see when you add another row

> ```
> CREATE TABLE my_test_table(var INT DEFAULT 0);
> INSERT INTO my_test_table VALUES (3),(4);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE my_sp_test_function() 
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE localVar INT DEFAULT 1;
>     SET @userVar = 1; ### If we swap this line for the one above the query works. ###
>
>     SELECT
>         @userVar := t.var + 1 AS return_var 
>         #@userVar := t.var + 1 AS return_var
>     FROM my_test_table AS t;
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL my_sp_test_function();
> ```
>
> ```
> | return_var |
> | ---------: |
> |          4 |
> |          5 |
> ```

you need here a Limit as else you get an error and MySQL can't use tables as Datatype, because Oracle would loose a lot of paying customers, i f they really would add  more functionslity

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE my_sp_test_function2() 
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE localVar INT DEFAULT 1;
>     #SET @userVar = 1; ### If we swap this line for the one above the query works. ###
>
>     SELECT
>         t.var + 1 AS return_var INTO  localVar
>         #@userVar := t.var + 1 AS return_var
>     FROM my_test_table AS t
>     ORDER BY var DESC
>     LIMIT 1;
>     SELECT localVar;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL my_sp_test_function2();
> ```
>
> ```
> | localVar |
> | -------: |
> |        5 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a4f5c4bfb4f90da3c929a4f78388211)*

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the wonderful additional explanation.